# Do you have any encountering

Tags: grammaticality, idiomatic-language

```
Do you have any encountering with C++?
```

What I meant to say is do you have any coding experience with C++, is the sentence above grammatical and idiomatic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not idiomatic. The way you expressed it in your explanation is much better.

Comment: Worth mentioning that in less "metaphoric" usages (where ***encounter*** has its "base" meaning ***meet***), the preferred format is ***Have** you **had** any **encounters** [with aliens]?* Either that or we just use the plain verb rather than the "nounified" version: *Have you **encountered / met** any aliens?* But ***encounter / experience*** are far from equivalent in such contexts - you might reasonably ask *Have you **encountered** C++?* in certain contexts, but *Have you **experienced** C++?* would be extremely "unusual" phrasing in any context I can imagine.

Comment: Agreed, completely.

Comment: (My comment was supposed to be a gentle nudge that you might want to *expand* your answer. Otherwise people might downvote it for being too brief, and/or lacking reference to relevant authorities, other examples, limitations, etc. :)

Comment: While I agree with your first comment, as I said, isn't it a lot for the learner who posed the question above to absorb?

Comment: It might be that it only looks like "a lot to absorb" because I don't have a clear picture in my head about what is and isn't relevant here (I honestly don't know). I do know that in some contexts, "experience" and "encounter" (and derivatives) are near-synonymous, but I *don't* know whether (or how much) my "literal / metaphorical" distinction affects things. If it's a *lot*, this may reflect a more general tendency that applies with similar terms - in which case it ***might*** be well worth learners making the effort to get to grips with what's going on.

Comment: Please answer with more than just "Yes" or "No". A good answer will explain "why" as well.

Comment: What if the answer is simply 'we don't say it that way'?